# How to create conditional edge among nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, py2neo

I am trying to create edges between nodes that share properties in neo4j. 
Each node has 5 properties say a,b,c,d,e. If 2 nodes share only property 'a' then edge will have name as 'a'. If 2 nodes share properties b,d,e then edge will have name as 'bde'. For each pair, if they share properties then ,I want to create a single edge only.
Thanks.

Comment: There are a few information that would help answering your question. 1. By the edge name, do you mean the `type` of the edge? 2. If so, can you use the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should create a `FOO` relationship with the `name` of a property that has the same value between every pair of nodes (that share any property values):

```
MATCH (m), (n)
WHERE ID(m) < ID(n)
WITH m, n, [x IN KEYS(m) WHERE m[x] = n[x] | x] AS common_keys
FOREACH (k IN common_keys | CREATE (m)-[:FOO {name: k}]->(m))
```

The `WHERE ID(m) < ID(n)` clause prevents `m` and `n` from being the same node, and also prevents duplicate evaluation of the same pair.

[UPDATE]

If you want only a single `FOO` relationship between 2 nodes, even if they share multiple property values, then this query should work:

```
MATCH (m), (n)
WHERE ID(m) < ID(n)
WITH m, n,
   REDUCE(s = '', k IN KEYS(m) | CASE m[k] WHEN n[k] THEN s + k ELSE s END) AS common_keys
WHERE common_keys <> ''
CREATE (m)-[:FOO {name: common_keys}]->(m)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your query creates multiple edges. So I made a change to create single edge with names like 'ade'.

Comment: Thanks for the update @cybersam. Is there any more efficient way for large dataset. Thanks!

Comment: This query produces Cartesian product and size of my data is very large (~ 1million). is there any more efficient way to create edges. Thanks!